# Java -- HTML client returns response before the complete page load

Tags: java, httpclient, httpresponse

I have to read contents of a certain field from a webpage. I have been told that I need to get the whole page and then extract the text from the html content.
I am using the following program to get the required page html content. 
Now the issue is that this webpage takes a few seconds to load the actual text value that I want to read even though the rest of the static page components are loaded earlier. And my program kind of returns the html content after the static components are loaded but before my value is loaded.  So, the final HTML that I get has the page loading process pic instead of the actual value. 
Could anyone please guide me on the required changes in this program that would help it wait until the page is completely loaded?

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://..../login");

    //prepare get method
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://...../value#/123");

    // add parameters to the post method
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "<name>"));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "<password>"));
    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity sendEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, HTTP.DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        post.setEntity(sendEntity);

        // create the client and execute the post method
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Statusline: " + postResponse.getStatusLine());


        //Output the Response from the POST
        System.out.println(getStringFromInputStream(postResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        //releasing POST
        EntityUtils.consume(postResponse.getEntity());

        //Execute get
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();

        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);//, context);
        System.out.println("Statusline: " + getResponse.getStatusLine());

        if (getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            throw new IOException(getResponse.getStatusLine().toString());

        System.out.print(getStringFromInputStream(getResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Comment: You are loading a page which contains ajax (javascript) and completed at the client side. So, you need to parse the javascript too.
I suggest using 'Selenium' package for this kind of task.

https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. Your suggestion worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

you can also use Jsoup library 
visit http://jsoup.org

Comment: JSOUP works to load website after JS evaluation. Not sure why people gave negative comments